# Is it possible to install different flavours of an app simultaneously?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created two different flavours of my application. Both flavours start with a different main file. If we assume the versions are called A & B then I run would run version A like this:

```
flutter run --flavor a -t lib/main-a.dart
```

This creates and install the debug apk of version A. Now when I do the same for version B:

```
flutter run --flavor b -t lib/main-b.dart
```

the already installed apk for version A gets overridden. I was wondering if there was a possibility to have both apk's installed at the same time.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I remembered `applicationIdSuffix`. This could work: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html In theory, if you have different `applicationId`-s, multiple flavors/types could be installed.

Answer (score 3):

For having multiple install of app you need to chang applicationId ( you can add suffix to current **ApplicationId** base on you flavor (in android)) 
so:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName_DEV"
    }

    prod {
        applicationIdSuffix ".prod" .   //or nothing..just remove this line
        resValue "string", "app_name", "AppName"
    }
}
```